# portal to communities migration licenses

Tags: customer-portal, licenses, community

I'm testing out Chatter Communities in a dev org. The org previously had Customer Portal enabled.

According to this (page 5) http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_portal_to_community_migration_cheatsheet.pdf
 I should have a Customer Community and Partner Community license options.

If I go to a Contact and select **Manage External User - > Enable Customer User** it takes me to the New User page where my license options are :

- Authenticated Website
- High Volume Customer Portal
- Customer Portal Managed Custom
- Customer Portal Managed Standard

I don't see any options for Customer Community or Partner Community. I then added Authenticated Website Profile to my Community and now if I select that it does generate a Community user (per the registration email, includes link with slug instead of temp. password). Though once a password is created in the Community this user can access both.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Do I need to do something else to see the Customer Community and Partner Community license options for new users?

Answer (score 2):

Phil, I have also begun to work on setting up a community in our org recently. I guess you need to buy these licenses in order to be able to see them in your org.

So if you have a Customer Community, the "Customer Community" license is the "Community" version of a High volume Customer Portal license.

From the License types docs:
http://na11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm

> The Customer Community license is similar to a High Volume Customer
>   Portal license and is well-suited for business-to-consumer communities
>   with large numbers of external users. The Partner Community license is
>   similar to a Gold Partner license and is well-suited for
>   business-to-business communities, such as a partner community.
>
> In addition to the new licenses, Communities supports all internal and
>   portal licenses including existing Customer Portal, Authenticated
>   Website, and partner portal licenses. Communities doesn’t support the
>   Chatter External license.

So based on this, you can create a user with the following licenses and should be able to access Communities.

```
Authenticated Website    
Customer Portal Managed Custom
Customer Portal Managed Standard
```

Comment: Ah ok makes sense, but when you enable a new user with Authenticated Website from a contact how does it decide which email to send between the portal and the community?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to contact sfdc to provision you the community licence(Partner and Customer Community) .For existing orgs sfdc will provision these licences on raising a request and if you purchase a new org then i think communities will be by default .For existing org the communities also work with portal ,Authenticated Website ,Customer Portal Managed Custom Customer Portal Managed Standard licences ,So you may play with these license in your existing org.